# Symbol Order for Built-in Functions such as TrigReduce

Tags: symbolic, trigonometry, order

I’d like to use the TrigReduce function on a sum of n sinusoids to any power, and am running into an issue with Mathematica’s default ordering of symbols.  Is there a way that I can specify an order of f symbols for TrigReduce, such that f1 < f2 < f3 {…}, while keeping notation symbolic?

For example, using numeric values work nicely:

[image]

But if symbols are used alone, I want to specify that f2 is the larger value in this example, so instead of f1-f2, TrigReduce would ideally yield the term f2-f1.

[image]

For perspective, the end goal is the general formula will output a list pairing each calculated numeric value with its associated symbolic f relationship (with f1 < f2 < f3 < f4, etc), but as it is, TrigReduce's symbol ordering doesn't always work as it doesn't know my preference for ascending values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `TrigReduce` doing this. *Mathematica* automatically sorts expressions into canonical order. The sort is basically structural/lexical, so knowledge of symbolic inequalities isn't applicable.

Comment: Is there a way to provide symbolic inequalities for functions though?  How would I use TrigReduce so it would yield the expression with the desired relationship?

Comment: Forget `TrigReduce`. It is not the cause of your problem. To see what's happening, type `Cos[x]-1`. *Mathematica* will automatically rearrange it. You could `Hold` your expression and then rearrange it internally, but that's complicated and requires a great deal of *Mathematica* expertise to do correctly.

Comment: One possibility is to make your output into a `List` with a substitution like `Plus->List`. Then sort that.